# why is the .git folder huge when cloning a hugingface repo?

Tags: git, git-lfs

I was downloading bloom using git lfs clone https://huggingface.co/bigscience/bloom --depth 1

It took all night long. I ended up with a 1.5 TB folder where the desired model were:

[image]

Alongside a huge .git folder, containing a lot of large unneeded files (I assume they are related to the changes, but I supplied --depth 1 to avoid this.)

So what are these files and how can I avoid downloading them, or alternatively, how can I clone a hugingface repo with only the models and no history?

Comment: This is the commit you've downloaded: https://huggingface.co/bigscience/bloom/tree/053d9cd9fbe814e091294f67fcfedb3397b954bb The files in it are huge (I downloaded one and it's really 4.6G) so the size is from models, not history.

Comment: then why are there huge  files in both the repo and the .git folder? I really only need ones in the repo

Comment: @user2741831 the repo and `.git` are the same thing. Do you mean that you only need the files in the working tree? Then I guess you can delete `.git`? Git needs to store the commit depth that it is on so all the blobs for the checked-out commit is in the repository. EDIT: Although I don't know if deleting `.git` is feasible given that you are using the `git lfs` indirection.

Comment: yeah but it would be great if it only downloaded the repo and not whetever is the .git. Which it does since the whole folder is 1.5 TB. Is there really no way to just get a snapshot of the repo and not download anything related to git at all?

Comment: It sounds like you want to (1) only download the latest commit (done) and then (2) resolve all the indirections by `git lfs` so that no data that you need lives inside `.git` and then (3) delete `.git`. Now you would have only the working tree of the (former) repository.

Comment: im not sure that is true. I cloned the llama 2 repo, and its .git folder was nearly empty. I don't think its just duplicates in there